# NUXT | 404 страница возвращает 200 код

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, http, nuxt.js

При переходе на несуществующую страницу сайт переходит на стандартный layouts/error.vue, но код ответа страницы 200 (должен быть 404), что сильно мешает правильной индексации.
Есть ли способ починить это?

Comment: привет, а ты нашел ответ?

Comment: Привет, да, нашел, я неправильно деплоил проект. Я деплоил его как статичный сайт ( просто выгружал содержимое dist), а нужно как SSR проект.

Comment: Как ssr проект - это ты как имеешь ввиду, можно пожалуйста чуть подробнее? Прокси прописывал к Node.js серверу имеешь ввиду?

Comment: Нет, на Nuxt же не только Single Page Application и Server Side Rendering можно писать, но и просто статичный сайт (просто после билда создаются твои файлы для конечного деплоя)

Comment: Я просто сделал деплой по
https://zencod.ru/articles/ssr-nuxt-beget/
и это решило мою проблему